# I'm greater in Hour than in Egg

Tags: riddle

A short riddle of hopefully moderate difficulty.

```
I am greater in hour than in egg.

I can feed you or help you sleep.

I'm not smooth but I can.
```

**What am I?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you:

> Sand

I am greater in hour than in egg.

> An hourglass contains sand as does an egg timer, but an hourglass would contain more sand

I can feed you or help you sleep.

> A sandwich can feed you (@MikeM.) or [the Sandman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman) can put you to sleep

I'm not smooth but I can.

> Sand itself is quite coarse and grainy, but sandpaper can be used to smooth things

Comment: Maybe sandwich would work, too?

Comment: @MikeM. Ah yes good point.

Comment: Perfect.  Well done SlashmanX.  Nice catch on the sandwich line Mike.

Comment: About the smoothness: Remember glas is smooth and also just considered to be sand. :P

Comment: @Zaibis Well it says "I'm not smooth" so I took that to be actual sand, and the "but I can" to be"but I can smooth [other things]"

Comment: ah ok, I understood it as but I can [be]

Comment: I found the last sentence quite trippy as well, wanting to put the extra 'be' in as my mind wouldn't let me interpret it as a full sentence.